# Joomla 3.0 MVC file upload in custom component backend

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file-upload, joomla3.0

SOLUTION: [How to Save Uploaded File's Name on Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927464/how-to-save-uploaded-files-name-on-database)

this ended up helping me.

i am trying to add a file upload to a custom component using XML and database.

I know how to get file upload done in a static PHP environment but my knowledge 
about the PHP MVC structure in joomla makes it so I am unable to add it.

What I have done so far:

•   Added the field in the XML file (of the type file)
•   Added the form fields in admin view project
•   Added an extra field My_project table(same as the image upload column)

Until this point it works.(fields are shown in admin backend component)

Now when you save the document with a file uploaded in the admin back end it does not save it to the database.

if i put media as field type then it works, but when i change it to file it breaks down.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>

  <field name="project_file" type="file"

            label="Upload file"
            description="Upload file"  
            directory="mysites" /> 


       <field name="main_image" type="media"

            label="COM_MYSITES_FORM_LBL_PROJECT_MAIN_IMAGE"
            description="COM_MYSITES_FORM_DESC_PROJECT_MAIN_IMAGE" 
            filter="raw"
            directory="mysites" /> 

 </fieldset>
```

**PHP file upload script i normaly use**

```
<?php
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

but what part goes in the model and what part goes in the controller?
and how to call it.

entire view is called in the controller

```
class MysitesControllerProject extends JControllerForm {

    function __construct() {
        $this->view_list = 'projects';
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $files = $jinput->files->get('jform');
        $file = $files['project_file']; 
        $this->upload($file);
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function upload($files)
    {
        $file_name = $files['name'];
        $src = $files['tmp_name'];
        $size = $files['size'];
        $upload_error = $files['error'];
        $type = $files['type'];
        $dest = "/home/vol3/byethost33.com/b33_13467508/bim-portfolio.cu.cc/htdocs/tmp";

        if (isset( $file_name)) {
            // Move the uploaded file.
            JFile::upload( $src, $filepath );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing new field in database and XML form is only half of work. You also have to write file save/upload functionality. There are two places you can do it. In controller (for example save task procedure) or model (there are 2-3 functions where you can do it). Look into this file `/administrator/components/com_media/controllers/upload.php` (upload procedure). I would just extend your **save** function so before data will be saved into database file will be stored on file system. You can find original save function declaration in `/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php` (for Joomla 3.0.1, for other versions it shouldn't be hard to find)

Here is sample save function:

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null){
    // youre file upload code

    return parent::save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
}
```

Comment: i checked the com media file and came up with the controller code seen above(eddited main post). however now it gives me a Warning JFolder::create: Infinite loop detected Warning: Failed to move file! --- and my tmp/log and global configuration are writble. and changing the $dest varible does not seem to work either

Comment: I think you need to do 2 things. First, get back to php learning cause you haven`t even declared `$filepath`. Then you pass string variable into `upload` function and you try to use it as an array.  Second problem is that you shouldn't run tasks in construct. I advised you to override save function so before data is stored in database you will move file. I think that you need to learn much more about object oriented programming in PHP. It is strongly recommended before you try to modify system or create extensions for Joomla or you will get stuck at almost every, even simple code.

Comment: the reason i put it the construct is becuase i am not able to call the methods in the model. normaly in c# i can just do CLass varible = new Class(); and then you can do varible.calltoMethod(), but Class::calltoMethod in php does not seem to work. and i know that in joomla that specific controller is called so i made a link there in order to test things out.

Comment: That's why I told you to learn more about object oriented programming in PHP. If you already now C++ it will take 3-4 days maximum to master it. I put above sample save function and marked where you should add your file upload code.

Comment: ty for your help: in reference i found another post for extra help on save topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280955/overwriting-jcontrollerform-save-method-to-trim-post-data-has-no-effect